# MySQL why does the order of these queries change the outcome?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two MySQL tables, one with a `DateTaken` and another with a `LastReviewed`, both storing date-time with values in the past. Both tables also have a `UserID` column (not index-unique) I have queries that are meant to shift forward all dates bound to a specific user so that the max value is right now. These are my queries:

```
// Step 1: calculate and store the offset
SELECT @offset := DATEDIFF(
   CURDATE(),
   (SELECT MAX(r.LastReviewed) 
    FROM `results` r WHERE r.`UserID`= 123     
)

// step 2: shift dates in drills table by the offset
UPDATE `drills` d
SET d.`DateTaken` = d.`DateTaken` + INTERVAL @offset DAY
WHERE d.`UserID`=123

// step 3: shift dates in results table by the offset
UPDATE `results` 
   SET LastReviewed = LastReviewed + INTERVAL @offset DAY
 WHERE UserID = 123
```

I run these queries using PHP's [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Something like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->multi_query("$step1; $step2; $step3");
```

Something really odd is happening but I can't figure out why.  If I run the queries in the order they are above, both tables get updated properly.  However, if I interchange steps 2 and 3:

```
$mysqli->multi_query("$step1; $step3; $step2");
```

Then the `drills` table (from step 2) does **not** get updated, but the `results` table (from step 3) does.  Why would that be? Seems illogical to me since steps 2 and 3 are independent.

Comment: Seems like the `@offset` definition does not compute do an actual value, but remains the statement. If you then change `results` it would also change `@offset`

Comment: @colburton that would explain it! It has big implications for performance though; it means that the first `SELECT` is run every time `@offset` is used whereas my intent was to store the value. If you care to write a full answer with links to supporting docs, I would select it. If you know how to actually store a value I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just a guess. I did not find any documentation on this behavior. The performance implications would not be that big, because the optimizer would certainly only make this part run once per query it's used in. So it is only run twice instead of once in your example. Worth looking into might also be to put all queries in one transaction.

Comment: This doesn't explain the behavior, but i would write the first statement as `SET @offset := SELECT DATEDIFF(...)` or as `SELECT DATEDIFF(...) into @offset`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks I wasn't aware of either syntax. Why would you use one of those instead? I assume it is so the value itself would be stored in `@offset`?

Comment: `multi_query` is **extremely dangerous** to use, and should be avoided in any production code that is exposed to the general internet. It makes it significantly easier to perform [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/). You'll also want to know the result of each query, not just assume they work and blunder along if there's problems.

Comment: I would expect all three statements to do the same except of that your statement would return a result. But again, for me that doesn't explain the behavior you described.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the note. I'm aware of those limitations of `multi_query` and I'm handling it with an abundance of caution

Comment: What you need here is a `TRANSACTION` and three separate inner statements. `multi_query` is not the answer.

Comment: @tadman What's wrong with `multi_query` in this context specifically? Note that there is no variable value. the UserID is hard-coded in. How would a transaction with three separate queries improve my outcome?

Comment: A few things. It doesn't guarantee atomicity, it doesn't allow error checking, and it means you're unable to use bound parameters. Other than those things, each of which is pretty serious, it's "fine" by an extremely loose definition of fine. The very function is so bad they really should remove it from the API. That you're not interpolating here is but one of the problems, and using this sets a bad precedent in your code base.

Comment: @tadman ok thank you. I'll follow the advice. I still would like to lean the answer to the question I asked in the OP

Comment: It's hard to say without some sample data. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) is a good place to set up a quick demo.

Comment: @tadman `UPDATE` statements are not allowed in fiddles. Only `SELECT`

Comment: To establish what sort of data you're working with here. It's unclear why order would matter unless re-ordering causes a syntax error. Do this as three separate queries and pay close attention to errors.

Comment: @BeetleJuice You can do updates in SQLFiddle just place the UPDATE query into the DDL text box - but I've found that site to be too unreliable lately and often use http://rextester.com or http://dbfiddle.uk instead